# Ubuntu will not restart without pullling the power plug

Tags: 16.04, boot

After an Ubuntu 16.04 update and a try to `shutdown` and `restart`, Ubuntu just scrolls a never ending repeated error message list. While I'm running Ubuntu, I keep getting the following error message on the screen:

[image: Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error.]

I've tried to report the error as suggested and restart Ubuntu without success.

Comment: If you open the terminal and type `sudo reboot`, what output are you getting?

Comment: Next time instead of pulling the power plug try holding down power button for 10 seconds. It sometimes does the same thing. Also what kernel version are you using? Use `uname -r` in the terminal and report your results.